# 3 Way Switches to Existing lights

Tags: lighting, switch, multiway-switch

I want to add a 3 way switch to my basement lighting. The circuit they are on includes a couple of receptacles also. The wire from light to light and receptacles is 14/3 Romex. The single pole switch is in a 2 gang box with a 3 way switch for the basement steps. All the white wires are bound together. All black wires are bound together with a pigtail to the single pole switch. The other leg on the switch has a red wire. The first light all blacks are bound together and the whites are connected to the white on the light. Reds are connected to the blacks on the light.

I have done a lot of 3 way switches before. Just want to make sure I do this one correctly.

Which wires go where on the new 3 way and on the new addition 3 way?

Comment: "A picture is worth 1000 words" goes the expression. Doubly so in the case of wiring. Please [edit] your question to include pics of all the different boxes involved and a drawing of what your proposed new set up will be. This will help ensure you get the correct answer, instead of merely educated guesses.

Answer (score 3):

Wire /3 cable **from the first switch to the new switch**.  Don't even contemplate any other routing.

3-way wiring is extremely bewildering due to the standard cable's wire colors being used for nonstandard things, so I *recommend* using yellow tape to mark both travelers. The travelers are interchangeable, no need to distinguish them from each other.

In this /3 cable, re-mark the white wire black, and the red/black wires yellow.

Also in your other wiring, anywhere black is *switched-hot* (hot when lamps are on), i.e. wired to a lamp, mark that wire red.

Red = switched-hot.
Yellow = travelers.
Black = always-hot.
White = neutral.

Now wire yellows to the travelers on the switches (brass/yellow screws).  Common on the far switch goes to black.  Common on the existing location switch goes to red.

Comment: This would seem to indicate that "neutral in all new circuit switch boxes, except..." includes an exception for "1 end of each 3-way circuit". Is that correct?

Comment: Is the coloring convention actually listed in an important reference? Or is that coloring scheme just a well known convention?

Comment: @popham fixed, sorry must've been in a hurry.

Comment: About 4 weeks ago I rewired a 3 way light that had 14/2 on two different circuits converging at the light. I discovered the problem when somebody re-energized the circuit I was working by flipping on one of the light switches.